# Yum not finding packages from added repo [CentOS 7]

Tags: centos, yum, fish

I am currently trying to install `fish` on a new CentOS 7 machine.

Followed the very straightforward guide which was:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/shells:fish:release:2/CentOS_7/shells:fish:release:2.repo
yum install fish
```

But when I run `yum install fish` I get the output:

```
No package fish available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

In `/etc/yum.repos.d/` the repo `shells:fish:release:2.repo` is there.

Is there any reason that yum wouldn't be finding the package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you install fish from the EPEL repository for CentOS/Redhat instead.

`sudo yum install epel-release`

Then if you try `sudo yum list fish` you should see it.

I know this isn't the answer to what you're asking, but I think it's the way to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Christoper, this worked. Not sure why this isn't suggested on the Fish website.

Comment: The reason is that the fish maintainers have no control over the EPEL repositories, and the fish you're installing from EPEL (2.3.1) is many releases behind the most recent release (2.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

I'd never noticed it before, but the CentOS builds failed for some reason. You can use the RHEL 7 repository, but I've kicked off a rebuild and it's succeeded, so it should work now!